# problem to set application name in android?

Tags: android, label

The problem with my application is that i could'nt see my application name under display icon. I used the following code in my manifest file to set application name and the icon for my project.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name">
```

After putting this piece of code in my application, i can see the icon but the application name(app name) does'nt appear at all. I even checked the string.xml file for the string app_name and i found it was also there.

I even tried to hard core the app name directly like the below,

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
              android:label="app_name">
```

but of no use i cannot see my app name. I was making a mess with this problem. can anyone suggest, what is happening here and what has to be done to display app name or is there anyother way to display my app name? Any suggestion on this is appreciable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name you see must be the name of your main Activity, the one which has the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

An Android application can contain several Launcher Activities, each one with a different name and icon. The name and icon you define for the application are displayed in the applications manager in the phone preferences.